# Download 120mb xyz.tar.gz file using Curl

Tags: php, curl

I am using Curl for downloading 150mb xyz.tar.gz file but after doing curl job its show **couldn't connect to host**.

But then i doing same thing with another url its working file.

Whats actual issue i am not understanding, please suggest me.

```
error_reporting(E_STRICT | E_ALL);

$output_filename = "data.tar.gz";
$user_agent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)';
$host = "http://api.innstant-servers.com:88/static.tar.gz";

$fp = fopen('./data/'.$output_filename, 'w+');

$ch = curl_init($host);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $user_agent);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $host);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$error = curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);

print_r($result); // prints the contents of the collected file before writing..
print_r($error);

// the following lines write the contents to a file in the same directory (provided permissions etc)
//fputs($fp, $result);
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: It is 120 (title) or 150(body)MB?? When you try to get from another url, it´s a similar weight .tar.gz?  Have you check  your download limit?

Comment: Actual .tar.gz file size 120mb and after extract its size approx 1.4gb, i tried for images only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to third party (IP) data download server firewall not allow to download data.
First need to add whitelist ip in firewall then data will be easily download.